# Android studio no me permite emular

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy usando **Android Studio** en una maquina virtual **vmware**, la maquina la he configurado tal y como en algunos tutoriales se indica con la opcion en el procesador `Virtualize Intel VT -x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI`.

[image: Configuración maquina 1]

[image: Configuración maquina 2]

He instalado la versión 3.0.1 de Android Studio. Tengo los siguientes paquetes instalados en la SDK.

[image: SDK 1]

[image: SDK 2]

Cuando inicio cualquier AVD este siempre me devuelve el mismo error (excepto en un caso).

Esto es lo que me indica el **Event log** de Android Studio

> 13:33  Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
>
> 13:33  Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!
>
> 13:33  Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!
>
> 13:33  Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
>
> 13:33  Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
>
> 13:33  Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Y este se muestra cuando el AVD *crashea*

> Android Emulator closed because of an internal erro:
>
> OpenGLES emulation failed to initialize.

Si muestro los detalles me indica lo siguiente:

> Operating system: Windows NT
>                     6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 CPU: amd64
>        family 6 model 42 stepping 7
>        1 CPU
>
> Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_WRITE Crash address: 0x0
>   Assertion: Unknown assertion type 0x00000000 Process uptime: 1 seconds

He montado 3 AVD distintos con distintas soluciones que he encontrado en la red.

Dos AVD tienen la CPU como `ARM` y otro la tiene como `x86` uno de los `ARM` tiene la opcion de `Graphics` en `Automatic` y el otro la tiene en `GLES 2.0`. El AVD con CPU en x86 no me permite cambiar la opcion de `Graphics` por lo que esta en `Automatic`.

Todas estas configuraciones dan el mismo error, por ultimo he probado con la opcion `Graphics` en `GLES 1.1`. En este caso, el emulador no crashea ni el **Event log** muestra errores, con esta configuración el emulador se congela y se le queda la pantalla en negro.

Tambien he probado otras soluciones indicadas en la red como: "Cambiar la resolucion del `config.ini` del AVD" y "cambiar el tamaño de la memoria en el `config.ini`"

Añado que cuando se congela el emulado me muestra el siguiente aviso:

> performing clean boot snapshot doesn't exist

La supuesta solución a este ultimo problema es desactivar el arranque del emulador a partir de snapshot, no encuentro esta opción en ningun lugar (las rutas que indican normalmente son de versiones anteriores).

Comment: La emulación en AMD solo funciona bajo Linux `AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (Linux only)
`  más info aquí https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html

Comment: @webserveis el procesador tanto de la máquina principal como de la real es intel, en el checkbox pone que hace la virtualización a Intel o amd supongo que lo hace a Intel ya que yo tengo intel.